# customizing Fancy box plugins

Tags: jquery, jsp, fancybox

I am new  to fancybox well downloaded from "http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/" i have images thumbnails and my requirement is that as the pop shown after clicking on thumnail i want show addition information as right side of image as we see in some social site, the information can contain comment or from user point of view the user can too comment on that photo.
The main problem is that the how to add custom div which will contain information. I am using jsp with spring MVC.

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider my (customized) fancybox "a la" facebook then :

http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxALAfacebook_26Mar12.html